# Select an aggregate / computed column from a view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I've created a SQL view that sums up the `amt` columns in another table:

```
create view blackjack_balance as 
select user_id, sum(amt) 
from blackjack_balance_change 
group by user_id;
```

This is working as expected:

```
mysql> select * from blackjack_balance;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | sum(amt) |
+---------+----------+
|      73 |        2 |
|      74 |       -2 |
+---------+----------+
```

But how do I select only the `sum(amt)` column?  This doesn't work:

```
mysql> select sum(amt) from blackjack_balance;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'amt' in 'field list'
```

Which makes sense, because there is no `amt` column in the view, and this does not seem to work either:

```
mysql> select "sum(amt)" from blackjack_balance;
+----------+
| sum(amt) |
+----------+
| sum(amt) |
| sum(amt) |
+----------+
```

What would be the correct syntax for doing that?  Desired output:

```
+----------+
| sum(amt) |
+----------+
|       -2 |
|        2 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud give this column a proper name. Like this

```
... select user_id, sum(amt) as amt_sum from ...
```

Then you can select that

```
select amt_sum from blackjack_balance
```

BTW MySQL uses backticks to escape "special" column or table names.

```
select `sum(amt)` ...
```